# Area under stress–strain graph

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain

What quantity does the area under the stress–strain graph (under the elastic limit) represent? As far as I know, the potential energy density due to strain is 1/2×(stress)×(strain). So does the area under the stress–strain graph represent twice the potential energy density?

Comment: Why do you think it's twice instead of the same? The area under the elastic portion is a triangle: 1/2×base×height.

Comment: by that logic don't you think area under v-t ( velocity-time) Graph ( if it's forming a triangle)Would be equal to  (1/2)*displacement

Comment: No, I don't think that.

Answer (score 1):

The graph in the linear portion represents the equation $\sigma (= E\epsilon) \times \epsilon$.

The area under the curve is the integral of the function from $0$ to $\epsilon$ that is:
$$\frac{E\epsilon^2}{2} = \frac{\sigma \epsilon}{2}$$

That is the elastic potential energy.